# Vkontakte api error in GetCampaigns

Tags: vk

I am trying to use `ads.GetCampaigns` method.
And receive the following error:

```
description = 'Invalid request: v (version) is required'
```

Everything worked fine for months. Don't understand what version it is needed. There is nothing about `version` in docs: https://vk.com/dev/ads.getCampaigns

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `v` parameter to your POST request to VK API.

For the actual version of VK API it should be `v=5.73`.